# Creating Docker image with springboot layertools - does not find profile specific application properties

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am following [the tutorial here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/01/27/creating-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3-0-m1) and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/creating-efficient-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3) on how to create a layered Docker image from my springboot backend.  I end up with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim as builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*-exec.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

The problem is that when I run this in my docker-compose with a Spring profile **TST**, that it does not find `application-tst.properties`.  I can see from the logs that Spring profile **TST** is active on startup, yet it only loads the properties from `application.properties`.

As a sanity check I copied the properties from `application-tst.properties` over to `application.properties` and rebuilt my image, which then worked fine (it connects to the database container etc).

I extracted the contents of my executable jar (which is the jar from line 3 in the Dockerfile) and can confirm that `application-tst.properties` is present there. Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it's a really dumb one...  The Spring profile is case sensitive, so

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=TST
```

should become

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=tst
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue for me. Spring does not inherit the environemnt variable for profile from docker build.